# php checking textbox containing a date field

Tags: php

Im using php and im checking if a textbox is empty (this textbox contains a date field)

I have something like this

```
  $startPeriod = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($startPeriod));

  if(empty($startPeriod){
   // do something 
   }
```

this if statement does not work because when a date field is empty it gets defaulted to "1969-12-31"

How can i fix this so that I can actually check if the date field textbox was empty?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it with a If condition

```
if($startPeriod != "") {
 $startPeriod = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($startPeriod));

  if(empty($startPeriod){
   // do something 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check it before itself like this.

```
if($startPeriod != ""){
   $startPeriod = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($startPeriod));

   // do something 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($startPeriod != "")
{
    $startPeriod = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($startPeriod));

    if(empty($startPeriod)
    {
         // your code 
    }
}
```